# text in navbar displaced on other sections of page

Tags: html, css

In certain sections of my site, the text within the navbar is a few pixels off compared to the other sections. (possible clue: section 'Austausch' and 'Mitmachen' are the two who do have the same positioning.)

[image]

I've not yet been able to figure it out, but I would guess that it has something to do with me manually setting the 'top' position trough inline-css. To not clutter this page too much, you can just view the source code by inspecting the webpage [here](https://fragmentum.art/).

Here's my style.css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    /*
      0% {
          opacity: 1;
      }
      49% {
          opacity: 1;
      }
      50% {
          opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
          opacity: 1;
      }
    */ 
  }
  
  .blink {
    /*
      -webkit-animation: blink 2s;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -moz-animation: blink 1s;
      -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -o-animation: blink 1s;
      -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    */
  }  
  
  
  html { 
background-color: #e7d8cf;
background-image: url("placeholder.png");
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: 150px;

  }
  
  
  
  
  
  html,body{
      overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  
  body { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   }
   
   
  
  .container {
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    background-color: none; 
    
   }
   
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .container {
          width: 320px;
          height: 500px;
      }
  }

  
   .header {
     position: relative;
     top:100px;
     width: 200px;
     height: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     padding: 0;
    }
    
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .header {
          width: 20%;
          height: 20%;
      }
  }
    
    .navbar {
    align-content: center;
    width: 500px;
      height: 20px;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 0 red;
      background: #faf8f7;
    } 
    
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .header {
          width: 20%;
            height: 20%;
      }
  }
  
  
   .box {  
     position: relative;
     top: 50px;   
     left: 50%; 
     display: block;
     float: left;
     width: 740px;
     height: 420px;
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 10px; 
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     border: 1px solid black;
     background: #faf8f7;
     /*
     box-shadow: -3px 3px 0px #000000; */ 
   }
   
   @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .box {
          width: 300px;
          height: 500px;
          left: 20px !important;
      }
  }
   

  @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .box {
        left: -50px !important;
    }
}
   
   
   .track {  
     height:100px;
     background-color:none;
     top:-30px;
     box-shadow:none;
     border:none;
     position: relative;  
     display: block;
     float: left;
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     background: #faf8f7;
   }
   
   @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .track {
  
      }
  }
   
   
   
   
   .nav {  
     margin-top:20px !important;
     /* position: fixed; */
     top: -960px;   
     /* display: block; */
     float: left;
     left: 50%;
     width: 400px;
     height: 20px;
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 10px; 
     /* overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden; */
     border: 1px solid black;
     background: #faf8f7;
     box-shadow: -3px 3px 0px #000000;
   }
   
   @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .nav {
             width: 300px;
             top: -1100px; 
             left: 21px;
             height: 30px !important;
  
      }
  }
   
  @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .nav {
        left: -50px !important;
    }
}

   
    .minibox {
     position: relative; 
     left: 20px;
     top: -280px;
     display: block;
     float: left;
     width: 260px;
     height: 40px;
     margin-top: 5px;
     padding-top: 10px; 
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     border: 1px solid black;
     background: #dbdbdb;
     box-shadow: -3px 3px 0px #000000;
     display: none;
   }
   
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .minibox {
          width: 20%;
          height: 20%;
          display: none
      }
  }
   
   .subbox {
     position: relative; 
     left: -11px;
     width: 761px;
     height: 330px;
     margin-top: -5px;
     padding: 0px; 
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     border: 1px solid black;
     background: #faf8f7;
   }
   
     @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .subbox {
          width: 319px;
          height: 330px;
      }
  }
   
   
    .blinktext {
     left: calc(50% - 70px);
     position: relative;
     top:50px;
     width: 200px;
     height: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     padding: 0;
     margin:0;
     color:white;
     text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000,-2px 2px 0 #000;
     display: none; 
     
    }
    
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .blinktext {
      display: none
      }
  }
   
   
   
   p, h2, a {
     
     font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     font-size: 14px;
   }
   
  
  
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .minibox {
          font-size: 10px; 
          width: 20%;
          height: 20%;
      }
  }
   
  

   a {
     /* font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace; */
     text-decoration: none;
     font-weight: normal;
     color: black;
  }
   
  img {
        border: 1px solid black;
        outline-offset: -1px;
  }
  
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .img {
          width: 20px; 
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top position has no effect here since it's static.

See here some documentation about it :
[MDN Web docs - top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)

The HTML code is different from one page to another, nav element in one of the page is nested into a `<small></small>` HTML element, in other page it is not. So you have to make uniform you code to expect a similar behaviour.